# Check when function finishes reading all the xmls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, function

I have a function which reads XML feeds from 7 different URLs and then add into the JSON object. I need to know when the execution of the function is finished and then i need to send Json feed to another function.

`simpleAJAXLib.init();`This is the function which reads all the xmls and put it into the Json object `jsonStr2`and i need to pass this Json object into another method.

```
passtoSecMethod(jsonStr2);
```

i am trying Promise but still the same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    d = new $.Deferred();
    myfunction();

    function myfunction() {
        promise = longfunctionfirst().then(shortfunctionsecond);
    }

    function shortfunctionsecond() {

        alert("second function finished");
        return d.promise()
    }

    function longfunctionfirst() {
        var URLCollection = [
            "http://news_national_3354.xml",
            "http://news_theworld_3356.xml",
            "http://news_sport_3168.xml",
            "http://news_ent_3169.xml",
            "http:///news_lifestyle_3171.xml",
            "http://news_travel_3325.xml",
            "http://news_money_505.xml",
            "http://news_tech_506.xml"
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < URLCollection.length; i++) {
            simpleAJAXLib.init(URLCollection[i]);

        }
        d.resolve();
        return d.promise();
    }
});
```

The alert should print when the longfunctionfirst finishes , but it is printing immediately when the function starts

Comment: You should look into promises

Comment: can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Promises should do the trick. They're not as hard as they may look like. Here's a tutorial: [promises](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/)

Comment: i have updated my question using promise but the problem is still the same can you check my updated question please

Comment: The part that needs to set up a promise/promises that you need to listen to are `simpleAJAXLib.init()`. When the `promise` sent into `simpleAJAXLib.init()` has been completely resolved, then you do your thing.